# How mobile top up sites work

Tags: android, mobile

I'm developing mobile top up site, and how i'm planning to implement the idea is below.
I've developed a site for user where they can input their mobile number with amount and pay the amount.
Then an android mobile is linked to this application will receive a notification and it'll make a request to company to transfer mobile top up to that number.

Can anyone tell me if this is the best way to implement this? OR can you please suggest me where I should improve my idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a thing called jolo which gives api for mobile recharge ,dth rechrge etc,
Please read this pdf it may be helpful http://www.jolo.in/Jolo_Recharge_API_Docs.pdf

Comment: I read the document you sent, and it looks like it will work for mobile networks in india. I'm just trying to develop a system on my own. No api usage. Can you please tell me how mobile top up sites actually work? I wanna know the complete life cycle.

Comment: I think it is not not so easy and as per my knoweldge  all the third party websites work on the basis apis provided by network operators or other third party apis which is a layer on the apis provided by network operators.I am sorry I cannot help you building the site from scratch